# Would time travel also be considered inter dimensional travel as well?

Tags: roleplaying, time-travel

This is a very important question to me because it affects my main character. Through his journey's with his party they managed to go back in time but without any knowledge of doing so until the very end. Now what is left of the party has clearly altered the time line; when my character returns to the present would that be considered a different universe? He now has knowledge of a world that he is no longer apart of and theoretically doesn't belong there. Should he have headaches(at the very least) to show that he has knowledge of two different universes? I feel my main question is would you consider the situation just time travel or inter dimensional travel?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about time travel, not RPGs.

Comment: See [this](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1609/15469) meta for more details about why this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Miniman This is about time travel inside D&D 3.5e (apparently). It's on topic and appropriate. If anything, the concern is that D&D 3.5e might have _nothing_ to say on the topic. That would generally be answer territory, but in this case we're specifically lacking certain details. Which leads to my next comment...

Comment: I am voting to close this as unclear: what is the method of time travel? If there is one mechanically in the game that is being used, that could give us guidance on the matter. If there isn't one, and this is all homebrew/narrative, there is no answer and asking us for guidance won't be appropriate for Stack Exchange - you'll just get opinions on how it should work, since this would be firmly outside any rules territory or anything we have in common for determining the result unambiguously.

Comment: We need to know more about your house rules on time travel.

Comment: After reading the rules in the help center it seems this question would be opinion based. Sorry to waste people's time.

Comment: Mate, it's not a waste of time to improve questions. If there is an established time-travel mechanic you *are* using that is sharable, we can certainly assess your situation via the rules and our subjective experience.

Comment: The only way we know how it works is that we found a coin with an hourglass on it that has magical properties and when one of flipped it we went back in time about two hundred years but only my character figured it out because he was the only one who survived aside from a new party member that was from that timeline so it didn't affect him.

Comment: Ah. Then yes, unfortunately "DM mind reading" is not a public-facing service offered by this Stack :)

Comment: If nothing else, it's worth reading up on the [very many ways fictional time travel might operate](http://science.howstuffworks.com/science-vs-myth/everyday-myths/time-travel6.htm), many of them with their own entire models of chrono-physics. Even knowing the method of travel is just a clue, and can't decisively determine the relationship between the destination time and "home" time. At the very least, reading up on the variety of time models should reassure you that you don't *need* to be having headaches. :)

Comment: I think that "what game is this" also applies, some games may cover such things. Also, does it matter? is this, I care because OCD, or does the difference between time travel or parallel universe timelines matter. If it matters then it's probably defined in the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There are no rules concerning time travel in 3.5 Edition.

AD&D 2nd Edition had a supplement called [Chronomancer](http://www.dndclassics.com/product/17442/Chronomancer-2e?it=1). Even then it was very confusing and would be even more so now. There are several deities that govern time and I am quite certain the moment mortals start altering timeways, their eyebrows would be raised.

Time, in and of itself, is a very special dimension. Even the spell [Time Stop](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/timeStop.htm) doesn't actually stop time, and even then, there are powerful outsiders that will investigate someone that uses it too much.

Time traveling to, for instance, go back in time to kill baby Vecna before he became a deity would cause so much trouble that a DM would probably just tell you to reroll a new character.

Time, for D&D 3(.5) purposes, isn't much of a "dimension/plane." See Temporal Plane (Manual of the Planes):

> The Energy Planes lack the traditional elemental forms of the other Inner Planes, or, if they have them. They are so unlike life on the Material plane that they don't interact
>   with travelers.
>
> Even by the standards of an Energy Plane, the Plane of Time is particularly empty of living things, whether visitors or natives. Most of the creatures there seem to be
>   trapped by some magical mishap or a failed attempt to capture time's power for themselves.
>
> Metallic constructs similar to golems and inevitables are liable to be found on the Temporal Energy Plane. Many of them are ancient creatures, their shells sandblasted to a
>   shining gleam. These creatures, originally sent here by spellcasters of bygone ages, have been trapped here ever since. Many constructs attempt to “mercifully” destroy new interlopers to save them from the eternal madness of the storm.

Another thing that would have more and more houserules flying at you is the Temporal Energy Plane's Time Loops.

> Pieces of other planes occasionally bob and weave through the storm, impervious to the effects of the winds of time. These are time loops, pieces of various planes that have become separated from their original realms. Time loops appear much as they did on their original planes, except their inhabitants take the same actions again and again, repeating themselves endlessly. A time loop is rarely larger than a few hundred square feet in area.
>
> On the Plane of Temporal Energy, time loops can be a refuge for those battered by the storm—and a possible way of exiting the Plane of Time. Should a newcomer to a time loop manage to interrupt the sequence of events significantly or complete a task that the time loop's inhabitants have never finished, the time loop returns to its original plane. This can be a blessing or a curse for the original inhabitants of the time loop, who have been living on a plane with the erratic time trait for years if not centuries.

---

## Suggestion

I suggest making it an alternate reality, similar to what [Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/en/) is doing with the [World of Warcraft: Warlords of Draenor](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/16690866/warlords-of-draenor%E2%84%A2-unleashed-expansion-now-live-11-13-2014), and having events that are similar with *your* timeline but different. Perhaps you didn't exist in this alternate reality, so you being there won't affect too much.

In this regard, the alternate reality could be a separate plane.

- Prime Material Plane A = Reality with you in it.
- Prime Material Plane B = Reality without you in it.

Comment: Time actually **is** a dimension. In the physical sense of the word, which is not the way it’s used in fantasy or sci-fi. It gets treated somewhat differently (it is not a fourth spatial dimension and space-time is not a Euclidean space), but nonetheless, it is another dimension like the three spatial dimensions (length, width, and height, as in 3D).

Comment: @KRyan I meant "technically" in the D&D sense of the word. However, I have been taught it is a temporal dimension purely to fit mathematical models. Like my physics instructor told me, "the dimension of time is simply to fill a gap so that we can explain how long it takes 1 + 1 to equal 2."

Comment: OK then, on a more topical note, 2E **did** have a plane known as Temporal Prime, wherein chronomancers.... chronomanced. As you say, it got really confusing, and chronomancers seemed to spend most of their time *making sure no one engaged in chronomancy* that I could tell.

Comment: As for "purely to fit mathematical models," the entire concept of a dimension (in this sense) is a part of a mathematical model, so that’s really all *any* dimension is. Certainly, it’s as reasonable to talk about **events** being located in **space-time** as it is to talk about **points** located in **space**, which is really the entirety of the difference. Does make a lot of the math easier, though.

Comment: @KRyan I added some information about the Temporal Plane from the Manual of the Planes.

Comment: It's probably worth holding off on this answer, or posing a new question for it. As it stands, this question is unlikely to be reopened. We *do not* recommend continuing to improve answers on closed questions, as it rewards leaving them closed.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Acknowledged.

Comment: If you would like, I can mod-delete this accepted answer when you find a better home for it.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Do whatever is best for this site. I will agree with your decision.